# Argocd login operation cancelled

Tags: argocd

I am trying to login via ArgoCD CLI to my argo cd server like so: `sudo argocd login **** --username **** --password ***** --loglevel debug`. However, I get the error `FATA[0250] Failed to establish connection to ****:443: dial tcp ****:443: operation was canceled`. I have tried various options such as `grpc-web`, `insecure`, `plaintext`. I am able to login from my personal machine (MacOS) into the argocd server I setup, however, from virtual instance I cannot. Is there any settings that would need to be setup for argocd login to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I was running the github runner as a virtual instance, and running argocd containers in cloud as well. I hadn't exposed a firewall rule to allow traffic from the runner into the argocd subnet.